# How do I loop through each record in my data model in a template?

Tags: javascript, ember.js

I have a model setup with Ember fixtures. My model is like the following:

```
App.Question = DS.Model.extend({
  isCompleted: DS.attr('boolean'),
  question_top: DS.attr('string'),
  question_bottom: DS.attr('string'),
  etc......
});
```

My fixtures (the actual data) is like the following:

```
App.Question.FIXTURES = [
   {
      id: 1
   },
   {
      id: 2
   }
];
```

I want to create a unordered list in my template that shows a "li" item for each record in my Fixtures. I think I need to use the {{#each question}} syntax but when I do {{#each question}}, it doesn't work.

How do I loop through my Fixtures data to create a unordered list, with one list item for each record in my Fixtures data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably your `question` property doesn't exist in your controller. If you are doing:

```
App.QuestionRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  model: function() {
      return this.store.find('question');
  }
});
```

You can use:

```
  <h2>Questions:</h2>
  <ul>
  {{#each model}}
      <li>{{question_top}}</li>
  {{/each}}
   </ul>
```

Give a look in that fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/marciojunior/25GHN/

Answer (score 0):

You need to return it to a route's model hook:

http://emberjs.jsbin.com/UGEmEXEy/1/edit

```
App.IndexRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  model: function() {
    return this.store.find('question');
  }
});

App.QuestionAdapter = DS.FixtureAdapter;

App.Question = DS.Model.extend({
  isCompleted: DS.attr('boolean'),
  question_top: DS.attr('string'),
  question_bottom: DS.attr('string')
});

App.Question.FIXTURES = [
   {
      id: 1,
     isCompleted: true
   },
   {
      id: 2,
     isCompleted: false
   }
];
```